# High CPU usage in libcurl with ssl url

Tags: ssl, curl

I am using 10 threads to connect to https connection. Curl is taking 100% of cpu. 
How can I reduce that ?

Each Thread Code is like

```
curl_connection = curl_easy_init();
```

Now using same connection

```
setting some header then 
curl_easy_perform(curl_connection);
```

Comment: Why do you want it to run slower? If you want more CPU for other things, `nice` the process. Most likely, what you are doing is CPU-limited, so it will use all available CPU to get the work done as quickly as possible.

Comment: currently we are running 10 crawlers then what will happen in the case when we started having 100 crawlers ?

Comment: and what about the cpu for other process. as My process is eating full cpu

Comment: Do you want it run slow or fast? It's your choice. You have only so much CPU. You can choose how to use it, but you can't make more of it. If you want other things to get higher priority, use 'nice' to give this process less CPU. Alternatively, you might be able to optimize this program to get more work done with less CPU. (Have you profiled it?)

Comment: yes . I had profiled using callgrind and it is showing 92% usage in curl_easy_perform

Comment: So it's the actual work of the connection. So you'll need to decide how fast you want to get the SSL work done and how much CPU you want to leave for other things and set the `nice` value appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce it by running other tasks, then the tasks will split the CPU. Otherwise, you want the CPU to do be doing as much useful work as possible. It's not like you can save it for later.

Answer (score 2):

For the others looking into high CPU usage solution in `libcurl`:
It uses a lot of CPU power to initialize a `libcurl` easy handle with `curl_easy_init()` and then to destruct it with `curl_easy_cleanup(_pCurl)`.
To decrease the CPU usage of `libcurl`, you need to create a pool of `libcurl` handles and reuse each handle by calling `curl_easy_reset()` on the handle. Alternatively, instead of implementing a pool of `libcurl` handles, you can initialize the handle once per thread and then in a loop before each new web request just call `curl_easy_reset()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call curl_easy_perform in main thread, avoid this, but call it in sub-thread.